# Aninut and food

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, mourning-aveilus

After the death of a close relative and before the burial (or the cessation of involvement with the body) one is in a stage of Aninut. During that time, one is exempted (or even forbidden) from many positive mitzvot, including [brachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91471/why-is-a-bereaved-person-not-even-allowed-to-make-a-short-blessing-over-his-food) on food, but is still bound to follow negative commandments.

However, if eating food without making a bracha is tantamount to [theft](https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/the-power-of-a-bracha/) (or me'ilah, misuse) and the commandment against theft is a negative commandment, why shouldn't an onein make a bracha in order to avoid transgressing a lav?

Comment: Isn't the answer pretty clearly that it's not actually a negative commandment here?

Comment: See the answers to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91471/why-is-a-bereaved-person-not-even-allowed-to-make-a-short-blessing-over-his-food/91499#91499

Comment: Some Rishonim (notably the Rash miShantz) rule that an Oinen does make blessings.
See אבני נזר או"ח סי' ל"ז, who discusses your question.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/berakhos-recited-over-food-mitzvah-or-matir?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a bereaved person not even allowed to make a short blessing over his food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91471/why-is-a-bereaved-person-not-even-allowed-to-make-a-short-blessing-over-his-food)

Comment: @sabbahillel No - that question asks about the idea of being distracted, whereas I am asking about the distinction between the aseh of making a bracha and the lo ta'aseh of theft.

Comment: Given that Hashem commands someone not to make a bracha means that the person cannot be considered guilty of *theft* (taking something without the permission of the owner).

Comment: Can we be commanded to do something which we are told elsewhere not to do? (I know that the answer is yes in some cases -- I'm just trying to figure out of this is one of those cases)

Comment: I've heard an explanation (b'sheim R' Soloveichik) that the "me'ila" of hano"oh from olam hazeh doen't exist in its own right, rather Chazal instituted birchos hanehenin in order to create the matzav of meilah for one who doesn't make the bracha. Meaning, it's not that this hano'oh was always subject to me'ila so Chazal came along and told us how to avoid the issue. Rather, Chazal, by instituting these brachos as a requirement before being neheneh from this world, made the hano'oh a sort of me'ila due to the fact that the person dodn't make the appropriate bracha. I hope this was clear.